# IBM Aspera delete file hook

Tags: bash, devops, file-transfer, data-transfer

According to [Aspera docs](https://download.asperasoft.com/download/docs/entsrv/3.9.1/cs_admin_linux/webhelp/index.html#dita/prepost_processing.html) we can create pre/post scripts for "Transfer" actions handling: like successful/unsuccessful file uploads. The result of file upload transfer - Manifestfile which we can use for future processing.

In case of file deleting from aspera there is no "Transfer" creation => no Manifestfile or smth like that. **Is there is a way to "listen" for file deleting by Aspera side and add hook to this action?**

Of course, we always can use ***inotifywait*** with target folder, but anyway on Aspera UI we have some kind of ["user action" logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB386.png), may be we can access this info somewhere else?

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find smth similar to my case in docs/Github/anywhere.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you refer to, is on the legacy site, prefer to use the more up to date site: https://www.ibm.com/products/aspera/downloads -> server -> documentation
i.e. : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ahts

I assume you are talking about "server side". i.e. a user uses some interface to delete files on server.

The picture shown is Aspera Shares, but there are multiple applications: accessing bare transfer server using desktop client, CLI , Shares and Aspera on Cloud... all of them enable to remotely delete a file on the server.

If the interface is the legacy "SSH" method with `ascmd`: Mmm not much can be done.

If the interface used is a web app, then it necessarily uses the "node api" underneath and in this case it is possible to get notification of file deletions using this API.

It is described here:
https://developer.ibm.com/apis/catalog?search=%22aspera%20node%22